# Is there a simple way to plot complex numbers satisfying a given criteria?

Tags: plotting, complex

I think this should be straightforward, but I cannot seem to find a good source on how to do it after searching around, so

I'm trying to sketch sets of complex numbers that meet a given for criteria.  For inequalities, I can get a sketch using RegionPlot.  For instance, I can obtain the inequality $|z| < 1$ by

```
RegionPlot[Abs[z]<1,{x,-1.5,1.5},{y,-1.5,1.5}]
```

However, given the equality $z + \bar{z} = |z|^2$ I cannot seem to figure out how to get Mathematica to sketch the set of point in the complex plane meeting that criteria.  Is there a simple way to accomplish this?  (I'm self-studying a complex analysis book that has a bunch of these exercises, and I'd like to just quickly visualize what's going on in all the examples.)  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `ContourPlot` for equalities:

```
ContourPlot[
    Evaluate[z + Conjugate[z] == Abs[z]^2 /. z -> x + I y],
    {x, -2, 2},
    {y, -2, 2},
    FrameLabel -> Automatic
]
```

> [image]

Comment: Great, thank you, exactly what I was looking for.  Obviously, I should have found this searching, but for some reason it didn't turn up.

Answer (score 11):

As David said, you can use `ContourPlot`. But if you'd prefer to keep using `RegionPlot` as you appear to have been doing, that could be fine too. All you have to do is to formulate your condition as an *inequality*. So I'll just copy David's code and do that:

```
RegionPlot[
 Evaluate@ComplexExpand[
   z + Conjugate[z] < Abs[z]^2 /. z -> x + I y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 
  2}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: RegionPlot]

Here, I also had to replace `Evaluate` by `Evaluate@ComplexExpand` to make sure there are no spurious imaginary parts (`0.I`) - `ComplexExpand` causes variables to be considered real numbers.

The boundary appearing in the `RegionPlot` is now of course the thing you're looking for, because it represents the equality.

Comment: Thanks, that's roughly what I had been doing, to get an idea, but figured there had to be a straightforward way to get it done rather than a work around.

Comment: OK - then I guess my main message here could be: `ComplexExpand` is useful when plotting stuff because it helps avoid spurious imaginary parts that often cause inexplicably blank plots...

Answer (score 8):

Let's define an appropriate function :

```
f[x_, y_] :=  FullSimplify[-(Abs[x + I y])^2 + (x + I y + Conjugate[x + I y]), 
                           Element[x | y, Reals]] 
f[x, y] // Expand
```

> ```
> 2 x - x^2 - y^2
> ```

To realize what sort of set is `f[x,y] == 0` we solve this equation :

```
sols = Last @@@ (Solve[f[x, y] == 0, {x, y}, Reals] // Quiet)
```

> ```
> { ConditionalExpression[-Sqrt[2 x - x^2], 0 <= x <= 2],
>   ConditionalExpression[Sqrt[2 x - x^2], 0 <= x <= 2]  }
> ```

```
Plot[sols, {x, -2, 2}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

We can use also `ContourPlot`, sometimes it satisfies one's needs even more than `Plot` or `RegionPlot` and in a straightforward way we make use of an option `Axes -> True` and add a circle where the contour line has the value `0` (i.e. `f[x,y] == 0`)  :

```
ContourPlot[ f[x,y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
            Epilog -> {Darker@Green, Circle[{1, 0}, 1], PointSize[0.01], Point[{1, 0}]}, 
            Axes -> True, Frame -> False]
```

[image]

Here the edge of the white circle (`2 x - x^2 - y^2 == 0`) was marked in a green color, and the other contour lines denote values `a == f[x,y] == 2 x - x^2 - y^2`,  respecitively for `a` in the following set : `{ -2,-4,-6,-8,-10}`.

We could specify as well to draw the only contour line `f[x,y] == 0`  this way :

```
ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Contours -> {0}, Axes -> True]
```

Comment: Very nice.  Obviously, I'm going to have to go read up on ContourPlot now :)

Answer (score 1):

Since V 12.1 we have `ComplexContourPlot` and `ComplexRegionPlot`

```
ComplexContourPlot[
 z + Conjugate[z] == Abs[z]^2, {z, -2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I},
 Axes -> True]
```

[image]

```
ComplexRegionPlot[z + Conjugate[z] <= Abs[z]^2, {z, -2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I},
 Axes -> True]
```

[image]