# Plotting transformations of loci in a complex plane

Tags: complex

I found the solution to plot loci of complex numbers [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4679/is-there-a-simple-way-to-plot-complex-numbers-satisfying-a-given-criteria), e.g. a locus of points of $z$ given $|z|=1$ is a circle centered at the origin with a radius 1.

But I am struggling to plot transformations, e.g. $T: w=2z$ would be an enlargement of the circle by a factor of 2.

I am trying something like this, but not very

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[w /. w -> 2*z, z -> x + Iy, Abs[z] == 1],
{x, -4,4},
{y, -4, 4},
Axes -> True]
```

Comment: The argument to `ContourPlot` is not what you think. Look at it before to try to plot it. `Evaluate[w /. w -> 2*z, z -> x + Iy, Abs[z] == 1]` evaluates to `Sequence[2 z, z -> Iy + x, Abs[z] == 1]` Also note that `Iy` is a variable not a product, you need `I y` or `I*y`

Answer (score 3):

So if you want to plot points that fulfill the equation `|z| = w` with `w = 2`. You can get the required result with

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[Abs[z] == w /. { z -> x + I y, w -> 2}], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, Axes -> True]
```

[image: contour of |z|=2]

Comment: {y, 3, 3} should read {y, -3, 3}

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for. I am looking for syntax where $z$ is as defined, so I can play around with $w=f(z)$... i.e. a general solution, not specific to this example.

Comment: You can use any equation in the contour plot you want. If you want to define a function `f[z]` you could use something like this: `f[z_] := 3 (z - 1)^2;
w = f[z] /. {z -> x + I y};
ContourPlot[Abs[w] == 1, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 Axes -> True]`

Comment: Still not what I am looking for. I need to be able to define $z$ as a condition for the locus instead of an equation. See the link in Q on how it was done for a plot w/o transformation. I need to extend that to a plot w/ transformation and be able to define the transformation separately.

Answer (score 3):

- Since `w=2z` means that `z=w/2`,so  we can plot `Abs[w/2]==1`

```
ComplexContourPlot[Abs[w/2] == 1, {w, -4 - 4 I, 4 + 4 I}]
```

[image]

- Another example by using `ComplexContourPlot`.

If you want to plot the mapping `w=(z+1)^2` under the condition `Abs[z]==1`,we can solve `z=Sqrt[w]-1` and plot `Abs[Sqrt[w]-1]==1`

```
ComplexContourPlot[Abs[Sqrt[w] - 1] == 1, {w, -4 - 4 I, 4 + 4 I}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 4]
```

[image]

- The same as `ParametricRegion` if we add the restricted condition `Abs[z]==1`.

```
reg = Block[{z = x + I*y}, 
   ParametricRegion[{ReIm[(z + 1)^2], Abs[z] == 1}, {x, y}]];
Region[reg, Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 BaseStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

- If we rewrite `Abs[z]==1` by `z=Exp[I*t],0<=t<=2 π`, then `ParametricPlot` also work.

```
Block[{z = Exp[I*t]}, 
 ParametricPlot[ReIm[(z + 1)^2], {t, 0, 2 π}]]
```

[image]

- Set  `MeshFunctions -> {Norm[{#3, #4}] &}, Mesh -> {{1}}` also means that `Abs[z]==1`.

```
Block[{z = x + I*y}, 
 ParametricPlot[ReIm[(z + 1)^2], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {Norm[{#3, #4}] &}, Mesh -> {{1}}, 
  MeshStyle -> {Thick, Red}, PlotStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None,
   PlotPoints -> 50]]
```

[image]

- `Abs[z]==1` is the boundary of `Disk[]`, we can use `ParametricPlot` again.

```
Block[{z = x + I*y}, 
 ParametricPlot[ReIm[(z + 1)^2], {x, y} ∈ Disk[], 
  BoundaryStyle -> Red, PlotStyle -> None, PlotPoints -> 50]]
```

[image]